# How can I compact a Table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I would be happy if someone could help me:
I have this MYSQL Table:

```
    -- ----------------------------
    -- Table structure for `massimp`
    -- ----------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `massimp`;
    CREATE TABLE `massimp` (
      `recid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Artikelnummer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Lieferant` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SafetyFilename` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SpecFilename` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`recid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
    -- ----------------------------
    -- Records of massimp
    -- ----------------------------
    INSERT INTO `massimp` VALUES ('1', 'T1503', 'SIGMA-ALDRICH', 'H:\\USERDATA\\MSDS-DEMO\\Sigma-Aldrich\\MSDS\\T1503_PrintMSDSAction.pdf', '');
    INSERT INTO `massimp` VALUES ('2', '101614', 'MERCK', '', 'H:\\USERDATA\\MSDS-DEMO\\Merck\\SPEC\\101614_494-Vitamin B12-111988.pdf');
    INSERT INTO `massimp` VALUES ('3', '101116', 'MERCK', '', 'H:\\USERDATA\\MSDS-DEMO\\Merck\\SPEC\\101116_AT_DE_0002_Food_and_Beverage_Campaign_Adulerants_Non-native_Amino_Acids_In_Milk_MM.pdf');
    INSERT INTO `massimp` VALUES ('4', '101614', 'MERCK', 'H:\\USERDATA\\MSDS-DEMO\\Merck\\MSDS\\101614_SDS_AT_DE.PDF', '');
    INSERT INTO `massimp` VALUES ('5', '101116', 'MERCK', 'H:\\USERDATA\\MSDS-DEMO\\Merck\\MSDS\\101116_SDS_AT_DE.PDF', '');
```

When I do a query like this:

```
      SELECT a.safetyfilename, b.specfilename, a.Artikelnummer,a.Lieferant from massimp a 
         join massimp b on a.Artikelnummer=b.Artikelnummer and a.Lieferant= b.Lieferant;
```

I get this output, which is not my wanted one:

[image: wrong output]

I would like to get a TABLE where

1. if safetyfilename and specfilename of an Artikelnummer is available his line should be printed - and only this line for the spec Artikelnummer.
2. if only one filename is available this the avalaible filename should be printed.
3. if no filename is available no line should be printed

Can someone tell me how to make this sophisticated in a MySQL Query?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: Yep. What's the wanted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN b.specfilename != '' THEN b.specfilename
        ELSE a.safetyfilename
    END AS filename,
    a.Artikelnummer,
    a.Lieferant 
FROM massimp a 
    JOIN massimp b ON
        a.Artikelnummer=b.Artikelnummer AND 
        b.Lieferant= b.Lieferant
WHERE (a.SafetyFilename != '' OR b.SpecFilename != '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark B, with your idea I could make it:

```
    SELECT 
        a.SafetyFilename,
        b.SpecFilename,
        a.Artikelnummer,
        a.Lieferant 
    FROM massimp a 
        JOIN massimp b ON
            a.Artikelnummer=b.Artikelnummer AND 
            b.Lieferant= b.Lieferant
    WHERE (a.SafetyFilename != '' and b.SpecFilename != '')
    
    union 
    Select
        a.SafetyFilename,
        b.SpecFilename,
        a.Artikelnummer,
        a.Lieferant 
    FROM massimp a 
        JOIN massimp b ON
            a.Artikelnummer=b.Artikelnummer AND 
            b.Lieferant= b.Lieferant
    WHERE (a.SafetyFilename = '' and b.SpecFilename != '')
    union 
    Select
        a.SafetyFilename,
        b.SpecFilename,
        a.Artikelnummer,
        a.Lieferant 
    FROM massimp a 
        JOIN massimp b ON
            a.Artikelnummer=b.Artikelnummer AND 
            b.Lieferant= b.Lieferant
    WHERE (a.SafetyFilename != '' and b.SpecFilename = '')
    ;
```